# Save all data frames in list to separate .csv files

Tags: r, list, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a list of data frames that I want to save to independent .csv files.

Currently I have a new line for each data frame:

```
write.csv(lst$df1, "C:/Users/.../df1")
write.csv(lst$df2, "C:/Users/.../df2")
ad nauseam
```

Obviously this isn't ideal: a change in the names would mean going through every case and updating it. I considered using something like

```
lapply(lst, f(x) write.csv(x, "C:/Users/.../x")
```

but that clearly won't work. How do I save each data frame in the list as a separate .csv file?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
N <- names(lst)
for (i in seq_along(N)) write.csv(lst[[i]], file=paste0("C:/Users/.../"), N[i], ".csv")
```

Following the comment of Heroka a shorter version:

```
for (df in names(lst)) write.csv(lst[[df]], file=paste0("C:/Users/.../"), df, ".csv")
```

or

```
lapply(names(lst), function(df) write.csv(lst[[df]], file=paste0("C:/Users/.../"), df, ".csv") )
```

Comment: As you can also access list items by name, you could even iterate over the names themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The `mapply` function and its `Map` wrapper are the multi-argument versions of `lapply`. You have the list of `data.frame`s; you need to build a vector of file names. Like this:

```
filenames<-paste0("C:/Users/.../",names(lst), ".csv")
Map(write.csv,lst,filenames)
```

What `Map` does? It calls the function provided as first argument multiple times and in each iteration its arguments are taken from the elements of the other arguments provided. Something on the line of:

```
list(write.csv(lst[[1]],filenames[[1]]),write.csv(lst[[2]],filenames[[2]]),...)
```